# Что безопаснее для реализации Producer-Consumer?

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Задача следующая:
необходимо реализовать систему, на протяжении жизни которой, в очередь будут сыпаться IO таски. Воркер достает таску и выполняет ее. Число воркеров конфигурируется. Встает вопрос, касающийся того, что система может быть запущена очень долгое время.

Потоки идеально предназначены для работы с IO, но мой коллега заверил, что чем дольше живет поток, тем больше риск того, что сожрется вся память. Вывод: потоки нужно создавать короткоживущие.

К тому же он сказал, что процессы в этом плане куда лучше: они могут дольше жить, для них не существует GIL(пока подпроцесс не создаст внутри себя потоки, но это ужасно), они изолированы и их ресурсами управляет ОС.

Так что же выбрать для реализации такой системы? Я пришел к выводу, что процессы, но тогда у меня вполне очевидный вопрос. Сформулирую его так:
если best practice в использовании потоков - делать их короткоживущими, то как следовать producer-consumer паттерну, используя threading, если планируется, что моя программа будет долго жить? Никак?

Comment: А почему вдруг должна сожраться память, если поток будет жить долго? У вас утечки памяти в вашей программе или в стороннем модуле? Если в стороннем, то процессы - это выход. А если у вас, так надо искать и устранять утечки.

Comment: Пока не могу сказать точно. Система в стадии разработки и никаких утечек быть не может, она еще полностью не готова, чтобы протестировать. Я интересуюсь здесь, чтобы их и не произошло. По словам коллеги - потоки долго жить не должны, иначе слить можно все. Он может заблуждаться, но я ему верю: он гораздо опытнее меня и долгое время работал с потоками/процессами.

Comment: Добавлю еще то, что он объяснил свои слова тем, что потоки постоянно переключают контекст. Это и сжирает память. Особенно если их много (а как я уже уточнил, количество воркеров конфигурируется)

Comment: Ну если вы разработаете систему без утечек памяти, то и проблемы существовать не будет. GIL для работы с IO не имеет значения; вообще, весь IO вполне можно уместить в одном-единственном потоке

Comment: Ну а если утечка памяти всё-таки случится, можно просто периодически запускать воркеры поштучно (раз в несколько дней или недель например) и не париться

Comment: По большому счету в контексте этой проблемы нет никакой разницы использовать процессы или потоки. Если вы используете процессы и готовы к перезапускам, т.е. система штатно переносит периодический перезапуск процессов, то вы точно также можете сделать и многопоточную программу, которая будет нормально переносить перезапуск.